# Re-render same component on route params change (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have code like this:

```
<BrowserRouter basname="/page">
    <Switch>
         <Route path="/test/:id">
              <Page />
         </Route>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When i switch from `/page/test/1` to `/page/test/2` the `Page` component won't re-rendering. I know the `componentDidMount` method won't be called but i want the `Page` component re-render.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this if you are using React v16.8 or above

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Page = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //Your code comes here to fetch the data from API
 }, [props.match.params.id]);

  return (<div>Layout</div>);
}
export default Page;
```

For Class components

```
<Route path="/page/:pageid" render={(props) => (
 <Page key={props.match.params.pageid} {...props} />)
} />
```

Comment: `Sathishkumar Rakkiasamy`, How can I do the same thing using the class component?